# Netezza CSV load

Tags: csv, netezza

We are new to netezza and currently trying to import a CSV file, via script, into netezza.

What is the best way to get this working.

Ideally we would like to 
1) Create the table structure we want
2) Import the CSV and map the CSV column names to the stucture we want

all in one import.

This code brings back the error: count of bad input rows reached maximum

```
INSERT INTO DBO.TABLE
SELECT * FROM
EXTERNAL 'C:\\log\\FILE.csv'
USING
(
 DELIMITER ','
 MAXROWS 300
 logdir 'C:\log'
 SKIPROWS 1
 Y2BASE 2000
 ENCODING 'internal'
 REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC'
 ESCAPECHAR '\'
 )
```

Importing by the wizard works but we can not automate this

is Nzload the way to go? If so whats the best practise with this?

--EDIT 
We have got this issue down to commas being in some of the fields we are importing and no text qualifier being specified in the import script.

How do we specify this?

Comment: When you say "importing by wizard" do you mean the tool provided in Aginity Workbench?

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, when your record delimiter present in your data you will want to make sure it is escaped with a backslash. However, in your case you can load CSV data using an option to allow double quotes around column data (which Netezza does not normally require).

Alter your code to include this external table option: QUOTEDVALUE 'DOUBLE'

```
INSERT INTO DBO.TABLE
SELECT * FROM
EXTERNAL 'C:\\log\\FILE.csv'
USING
(
 DELIMITER ','
 MAXROWS 300
 logdir 'C:\log'
 SKIPROWS 1
 Y2BASE 2000
 ENCODING 'internal'
 REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC'
 ESCAPECHAR '\'
 QUOTEDVALUE 'DOUBLE'
 )
```

Answer (score -1):

PLZ use the duble slase \

INSERT INTO DBO.TABLE
SELECT * FROM
EXTERNAL 'C:\log\FILE.csv'
USING
(
 DELIMITER ','
 MAXROWS 300
 logdir 'C:\log'
 SKIPROWS 1
 Y2BASE 2000
 ENCODING 'internal'
 REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC'
 ESCAPECHAR '\'
 )